# How to create import button in system configuration and save import CSV data in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, importexport

I need like Table Rates Shipping Import / Export CSV. I have used this reference:: [$_FILES in Magento2 ECG : system configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135694/files-in-magento2-ecg-system-configuration).
but it's not working for me. Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: New method to set Csv..now my Code working..

Comment: @Magento2Developer How  import work? please explain